# Rails please do not add /assets/ to my image urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three folders in the public folder:

```
 uploadsave
 uploadnew
 uploadocr
```

All this folders contain images. What annoys me is that the asset pipline adds to my image urls /assets/. The problem that with this urls my images wont display! So how can i delete this three folders from the asset pipline or avoid this behaviour?

Comment: when you say your images wont load what path are you using to call them?

Comment: for example /uploadsave/filename.jpg and rails makes /assets/uploadsave/filename.jpg What is not working

Comment: its working fine, try /assets/uploadsave/filename.jpg, or /assets/filename.jpg, cant remember off the top of my head.. the asset pipeline is an awesome feature of rails, there is no need to avoid this behavior as you say...oh and why use the public folder?

Comment: Im only concerned because i read that the asset pipline loads all files in the folders! And i have around 1000 images in that uploadsave folder!

Comment: read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you start your image paths with `/` they are relative to the projects document root, which is the public folder.

`image_tag 'foo.png'` is rendered to `/assets/foo.png`
`image_tag '/uploadsave/foo.png'` is rendered to `/uploadsave/foo.png` which is served from `public/uploadsave/foo.png`.

Comment: ok for example if i have an image.png in public/uploadsave  how do i refer to it?

Comment: see the added examples